# "you can't perform that action at this time" error when using github GUI to pull and merge

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Hello i got some issue when i try to do the pull request in github.

This is the step2 that i did before i do pull request :

1. i create my localbranch ( git checkout -b exampleBranch )
2. i make some changes.
3. i save it in stash
4. i request pull in GIT Bash ( git pull origin myBranch )
5. i use git stash pop to get my changes back.
6. i add, commit and push to my exampleBranch
7. i go to gui github to pull my exampleBranch ( pull and merge)
8. and when i tried to pull it. I got error information, it says "you cant perform that action at this time"

i tried to search it in google, and i already disable all of web extension ( i dont know if this step is related to this issue )

i dont know if anyone has same issue as me.

I really appreciate for those who want to participate to help me solve this issue.

kindly see the attachment.

*Sorry for any grammatical mistakes

Before
[image: Before Request]
Error massage. 
[image: Error msg]

Comment: Hi Iman, welcome to SO! Let's try some basic debugging (it would also help to add this information to your question): are you the owner of the repository? When you "pull and merge" using Github GUI, do you actually mean "squash and merge" the pull request? Are you trying to merge your branch into the master branch? Are there other people working on your branch (it sounds like there are) - in which case - are you the author of the pull request? Maybe add that info to your question as it will help people (like me) help you solve your problem!

Comment: Hello @GrayedFox, thank you so much for helping me to figure it out whats the issue that i have right now

1. Im not the author of this repository. (should i ask something to the owner?)
2. hmm yeah i think so, because what i wanted to do, i want to merge my branch to master branch.
3. actually only me that working on this branch, there is no viewer , no antoher dev that working on this repo.

thank you so much :)

Comment: It sounds like a permissions issue. You will need to contact the owner of that repository and check you have permissions to squash and merge your pull request against master (sometimes only repository admins or those with edit rights can perform this action).

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time this happens because the repository's owner restricted or blocked you rights on editing. Contact the repository owner and ask them to fix the permissions.

Comment: Yes, I have tested that now and reproduce. And for forking there's a related "You can't fork this repository at this time": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145921/cant-fork-a-repository-on-github/67354715#67354715

Comment: Yeah, it is the same. The owner might block your rights to fork your repo.