# Can't fork a repository on GitHub

Tags: github, git-fork

I'm trying to fork [this](https://github.com/klange/ponyos) repository, but getting an error message:

> You can't fork this repository at this time.

[image]

I've read the license, and tried forking from another computer using VPN, in case of security conflict of my browser and GitHub, but it still  don't work, and I can't even guess why so. Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: PS you could and an image by pasting the image into the stackoverflow message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a temporary GitHub issue.

Creating a fork isn't dependent of a license or vpn. It's just a http call in your browser.

Update: I forked the repo without issue.

Comment: I've just don't know what to think :)<br>    
"star" button is not active, fork attempts ends with an uninformative "you can't fork this repository at this time" since my first try in summer, so I've started to seek problems in all possible directions.. Thanks for help, at least I know that problem is in my account! (probably, I can just ask a friend to fork it for me)

Comment: Then I would recommend to contact GitHub. Those guys are really helpful.

Answer (score 7):

**This also happens if the user has blocked you**

Tested today, May 2021.

A similar related message if you try to open an issue on a repository whose owner blocked you is:

> You can't perform that action at this time.

You can just manually create a new repository and reupload the code there however. You just won't be able to send pull requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a fork of the original repo, you cannot have another fork.
You can add the other repo as a remote though and use code from there.

Comment: While not relevant to this particular question. I did arrive to this page through a Google search, and this was the answer to my question. I couldn't fork a repo because I had already forked it. GitHub just didn't tell me this. I feel like GitHub should include a link to your account's fork when clicking that fork button.